# Is there any solution to prevent the express sessions from drop every time you perform server restart without using RedisStore?

Tags: node.js, express

I can perform other operations on dashbord even server restart without reload the webpage

Comment: No. You need some storage. otherwise it won't store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are not using any kind of persistence storage for your sessions. In that case the sessions are stored in memory of the express app. Hence a restart would drop all the sessions. You either need a cache like Redis or even postgres to persist your sessions.